# Create table with checksum of all tables in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to determine if a table has been affected by a number of processes that run in sequence, and need to know what the state of the table is before and after each runs. What I've been trying to do is run some SQL before all the processes run that saves a before checksum of every table in the db to a table, then running it again when each ends and updating the table row with an after checksum. After all the processes are over, I compare the checksums and get all rows where before <> after.

Only problem is that I'm not the best guy for SQL, and am a little lost. Here's where I'm at right now:

```
select checksum_agg(binary_checksum(*)) from empcomp with (nolock)

create table Test_CheckSum_Record ( TableName varchar(max), CheckSum_Before int, CheckSum_After int)


SELECT name into #TempNames
FROM sys.Tables where is_ms_shipped = 0
```

And the pseudocode for what I want to do is something like

```
foreach(var name in #TempNames)
insert into Test_CheckSum_Record(name, ExecuteSQL N'select checksum_agg(binary_checksum(*)) from ' + name + ' with (nolock)', null)
```

But how does one do this?

Comment: Are you only looking for Alterations on CRUD operations or do you want to recalculate the sum when the table structure/constraints changes as well?

Comment: Just CRUD operations. The schema shouldn't change at all. Effectively, I just need to know if the data any table changed, and if so which table.

Comment: Do all tables that you want to check have an IDENTITY column?   If not, this may not be a viable approach.

Comment: If you want to determine whether a table has been affected by your processing you could sue change tracking or CHANGETABLE

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comments you need to create a trigger that handles all CRUD operations and just places a flag

Syntax is

```
Create TRIGGER [TriggerName] ON [TableName]
AFTER UPDATE, AFTER Delete, AFTER UPDATE
```

In the trigger you can do a

`select CHECKSUM_AGG([Columns you want to compare against]) 
   from [ParentTable]` store that value in a variable and check it against the checksum table before column. If it does not exist you add a new entry with the `DELETED` tables checksum_AGG value as the before entry

Please note the choice not to use the inserted table is just preference for me on calculated columns

I will edit later when I have more time to add code